# Year value returned from Oracle is incorrectly shown as 0013

Tags: java, oracle

I have a `TIMESTAMP` field that contains the data: `13-09-16 23:56:00.000000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK`

I am sourcing this data from Java into a Calendar object and the year is expressed as `0013`. SQL developer also expresses the date when run with `to_char(order_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')` as `0013`.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

'RR' or 'RRRR' - year format

'RR' Lets you store 20th century dates in the 21st century using only two digits.
See Also: Additional discussion on RR datetime format element in the Oracle
Database SQL Reference

'RRRR' Round year. Accepts either 4-digit or 2-digit input. If 2-digit, provides the same
return as RR. If you do not want this functionality, then enter the 4-digit year.

Oracle® Database
SQL Quick Reference
10g Release 2 (10.2)
B14195-01

Answer (score 1):

Your field is incorrectly formatted, it should be `2013-09-16 23:56:00.000000000`. If you are storing this in an SQL Timestamp column, the database should automatically correct this (or it will change it to `0013-09-16 23:56:00.000000000`).

The reason for both SQL developer and in Java that you're getting 0013, is because you're requesting the format to be a four-digit year `YYYY`, when the value is a two-digit year. You would need to specifiy `YY` to get two digits.

At the core of the problem though, your timestamp is not being stored correctly.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll have to look into how the date is being parsed and added to the database. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is pretty out of date, but I figured I would add my solution as the TO_CHAR function has never worked for me.

Use the 
    `TO_DATE(yourDateField,'DateFormat')`

This should put it in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the pattern:

```
to_char(order_date,'YY-MM-DD')
```

YYYY is for four numbered years

YY should work for years with two digits (maybe it will e displayed as 1913 not 2013)

Answer (score 0):

If SQL returns `to_char(order_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')` as `0013-nn-nn`, this means that the year *is actually* the year 13AD, so it's correctly showing `0013`.